# Jenkins jobs and GIT/maven structure

Tags: java, git, maven, jakarta-ee, jenkins

I'm new in Jenkins and I don't know what's is the best practice to handle multiple maven modules.
My project consists of 5 different maven projects. One of this project is maven parent project which builds the rest. Each of these 5 maven projects is located in separate GIT repository.

Should I have one job for each GIT repository or is it possible to configure it in a different way?

Comment: Introduce your modules as submodules into your main repo. This way you can keep everything in seperated repos and in the meantime you can manage it from a single place (top level). This will help you make a jenkins job because in general a jenkins job is bound to a repository.

Answer (score 2):

My best practice for it that you should put all projects in one GIT Repository, that are released together, since you tag and branch the whole repository in GIT. If a project has another release cycle, put it in another repository.

Example:

You have 5 Project A, B, C, D and E. A, B and C are for examples projects that represent one level in zour architecture of your application. D and E are helper libraries that will change occasionally but not with each release of your application. (e.g. additional GUI elements,...)

In this Case I would use three repos:

First Repo:

```
Parentpom for A, B, C
    A as module of ParentPom
    B 
    C
```

Second Repo:

```
 D
```

Third Repo:

```
 E
```

You can also start having all Project in one repository when you start the project and all Maven projects, even the libraries will change regularly and then "refactor" your repo structure later on when you notice that you don't release some projects together with others.

Your Jenkins Job structure will be the same as your repositories, e.g. when you have three repos as im my example aboth, you have three Jenkins Jobs (each one for the root pom inside each repository)

Comment: In your opinion, a "best practice" must match all situation and is objective. But it is not. A "best practice" is always a compilation of experiences based on specific situations. This applies that is subjective since it concludes only the experiences of a small group.

What I meant here is that I have very good experiences with the first approach for large projects, and that is my best practice for that situations. If you want to start simple, use the second approach, but you will reach a point where that will become impractical and you need to refactor to the first approach.

Comment: You miss the point.  If something "best practice" it is "best practice".  Saying something is "*my* best practice" is a contradiction!  It is bad English and semantically nonsensical.

Comment: Sorry for the bad language, but no "Institute of prest practices" approved my oppinion that my experiences are THE best practice. Therefor I accentuate the fact that there might be other practices that some other say its a best practice.

Comment: Jens - that is correct.  It is your opinion.  Claiming that it is "best practice" requires evidence that most people would agree with that it best practice.  When you call it "*my* best practice" you are (unintentionally ... I guess) confusing the issue.  (It is like me saying "my 100 metre world record" to refer to my *personal* best time over 100 metres.)

Answer (score 0):

You can specific the dependency repositories in maven of parent project and build them accordingly. Even if your dependency increases you can add them to your parent project and build them in future.